# SQL Query to ASP.NET LINQ Query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

What is the equivalent .NET LINQ Query for the below SQL Query?

```
select * 
from customers 
where CUSTOMERID not in ('123','321')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    var exceptList = new List<string> {"123","321"};
    var target = (from item in Db.customers select item.CUSTOMERID ).Except(exceptList);
```

Answer (score 0):

For only those two values `123` and `321` you can simple do this:

```
var results = Customers.Where(c => c.CUSTOMERID != 123 && c.CUSTOMERID != 321);
```

For a list of values, something like `nums` where nums is an array of `CUSTOMERID` you can do this:

```
var nums = new int[]{123, 321};
var results = Customers.Where(c => !nums.Contains(c.CUSTOMERID));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from d in Members
where d.CUSTOMERID !=123 || d.CUSTOMERID !=321
select d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var ids=new[]{'123','321'};
var results=    from x in Customers
    where !ids.Contains(x)
```